# simple autohotkey can't seem to read ini file

Tags: autohotkey

i'm trying to read ini file, however it cannot seem read the ini file, even i put on or off only the first statement runs, any idea why? i'm kinda new to autohotkey, i hope you help me thank you

```
home::
Loop

    {
     test() 
     sleep, 1500 
    }


test() {
IniRead, value, skillmode.ini, skillmode, toggle

if(%value% = on) {
 send, {f9}      
 msgbox, now its on!
 return

}    
else if(%value% = off) {    
     send, {f5} 
     msgbox, now its off!
     return
    }
else {
msgbox, nothing happened
return
}
}
```

and heres in my skillmode.ini file

```
[skillmode]
toggle=off
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code:

1 - You can not use in a if-statement - example - if(%value% = off) and if(%value% = on) it must be if(value = "off") and if(value = "on")

2 - and You are missing at the bottom a extra **Return** Command you will need it, for the **home::**

You can Try this AHK code, i did test it out on my Windows 10 System and it works.

With the f4 key you can test it out.

This simple autohotkey script will read a value from a .ini file.

test.ahk

```
; [+ = Shift] [! = Alt] [^ = Ctrl] [# = Win (Windows logo key)]
f4::

Loop
{
gosub test 
sleep 1500 
}


test: 
IniRead, value, skillmode.ini, skillmode, toggle

if (value = "on") 
{
send {f9}      
msgbox now its on! %value%
return
}

if (value = "off") 
{    
send {f5} 
msgbox now its off! %value%
return
}

msgbox nothing happened %value%
return

return
```

The skillmode.ini File is:

```
[skillmode]
toggle = off
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
home::
    Loop {
        test()
        sleep, 1500 
    }
return ; Missing a Return

test() {
    iniFile := A_scriptDir "\skillmode.ini" ; Full Directory Path A_ScriptDir
    IniRead, value, %iniFile%, skillmode, toggle
    ; value not %value% , == instead of = , Quotes around Strings 
    if (value == "on") { 
        send, {f9}      
        msgbox, now its on!
        return
    } else if ( value == "off") {    
        send, {f5} 
        msgbox, now its off!
        return
    }

    msgbox, nothing happened
    return
}
```

Note about your .ini file. I found my files were being saved with Encoding UTF-8, this caused a problem with IniRead, but was fixed when I changed it's Encoding to ANSI.